# Summary Percentage Yes vs No

Tags: crystal-reports

Basically I'm looking for a formula to see how many times `Yes` was used vs. `No`.

I have something like this:

```
(({Command.result} ="Yes") / {Command.result})*100
```

Which makes sense in my head, but I keep getting:

> A number, or currency amount is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current formula attempts to divide a boolean type through by a string. You can only perform division with numbers.

Instead, create two formulas as individual counts of Yes or No:

**@YesCount:**

```
If ({Command.result} = "Yes") Then 1 Else 0
```

**@NoCount:**

```
If ({Command.result} = "No") Then 1 Else 0
```

---

For the percentage, create two more formulas:

**@YesPercent:**

```
100 / Count ({Command.result}) * Sum ({@YesCount})
```

**@NoPercent:**

```
100 / Count ({Command.result}) * Sum ({@NoCount})
```

Comment: I get your logic, I have to change to 1s and 0s to sum. But how do I get that to a percentage?

Comment: Actually I just realized, for: `If ({Command.result} = "Yes") Then 1 Else 0` it's just adding up to 1 for some reason, even though there are lot  of 'Yes's

Comment: Thats not the way crystal-reports works. The formula is evaluated for each record. You need to add a sum for `YesCount` and `NoCount`.